# Can't get the ID from a navbar list href

Tags: c#, .net

this is my first question, so hopefully I won't screw it.
This is .net framework 3.5
The MasterMenu.ascx has a navbar list and each item redirects to a specific url. And each item from the list has an ID.
What I'm (unsuccessfully) trying to do is, given the URL, get the ID of the item who send it there.
I.E. (MasterMenu.ascx):

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown" id="DropDownPF” runat="server" visible="false"><a id="A2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">PF<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                        <li visible="false" id="DropDepositSSN" runat="server"><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(“~/Deposit.aspx")%>">Deposit </a></li>
                        <li visible="false" id="DropPFSSN" runat="server"><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(“~/Check.aspx")%>">Check</a></li>
                        <li visible="false" id="DropInterfaceSSN" runat="server"><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Interface.aspx")%>">Interface</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

When I get the current path, lets say

> ~/Check.aspx

I want a method that returns the id of the item:

> DropPFSSN

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not maintain a Dictionary<string, string> and put the mappings there?

Comment: Hey thanks. Yeah, it's possible but I don't want to "hardcode" that. It's a good workaround but, what I'm asking it's simply not possible?